# read cell excel win32com

Tags: python, win32com

My problem is that the price when printing does not move

The price I took from excel

[image]

[image]

I want to read a cell then print the prices and keep changing

```
enter code here
from win32com import client as client
import time
excel = client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible= True
wz=excel.Workbooks.Add()
def m():
wp=wz.Worksheets.Add()
   wp.Name = "hihuih"
   time.sleep(10)
   return wp
x=m()
while True:
  p=x.Range("A1:A1").Value
  time.sleep(0.1)
print(p)
```

Comment: Hello, is there any way you can add more detail on what you're trying to accomplish as well as maybe more information on what your code snippet seeks to do? It is hard to help review/edit/answer this question as it currently stands due to lack of information.

Comment: I have a problem that a repeat loop stops giving me a line that I do not want a repeat loop stop

Comment: It is important to me that the price is always printed

Comment: Have you seen a picture
  Stop price that I want it to change
Price in execl varies